# Converting to Float for Math Operations

Tags: java, android-studio

Writing a program in Android Studio 2.2.2 (MainActivity.java). Basically there are multiple inputs, one button, multiple outputs. However, many of the outputs are cross referenced into many of the other outputs. I'm new to all of this as our professor threw this on us in a non-programming class. Can anyone see some of my errors? I hope that I'm doing the process mostly correct, but the operations are all have issues with string/float/double incompatibilities. Thanks for any insight!

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button btnCalc;
private TextView tvaResult;
private TextView tvcResult;
private TextView tvetResult;
private TextView tvphiResult;
private TextView tvMnResult;
private TextView tvphiMnResult;
private TextView tvbeta1Result;
private EditText etB,etD,etH,etAs,etFc,etFy;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    btnCalc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
    etB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etB);
    etD = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etD);
    etH = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etH);
    etAs = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAs);
    etFc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFc);
    etFy = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFy);
    tvaResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvaResult);
    tvcResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcResult);
    tvetResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvetResult);
    tvphiResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvphiResult);
    tvMnResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMnResult);
    tvphiMnResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvphiMnResult);
    tvbeta1Result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvbeta1Result);

    btnCalc.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        Float B = Float.parseFloat(etB.getText().toString());
        Float D = Float.parseFloat(etD.getText().toString());
        Float H = Float.parseFloat(etH.getText().toString());
        Float As = Float.parseFloat(etAs.getText().toString());
        Float Fc = Float.parseFloat(etFc.getText().toString());
        Float Fy = Float.parseFloat(etFy.getText().toString());
        Float aResult = Float.parseFloat(tvaResult.getText().toString());
        Float cResult = Float.parseFloat(tvcResult.getText().toString());
        Float etResult = Float.parseFloat(tvetResult.getText().toString());
        Float beta1Result = Float.parseFloat(tvbeta1Result.getText().toString());
        Float phiResult = Float.parseFloat(tvphiResult.getText().toString());
        switch(view.getId() ) {
            case R.id.btnCalc:
                tvaResult = (Fy * As) / (0.85 * Fc * B);
                tvcResult = aResult / beta1Result;
                tvetResult = ((D - cResult) / (cResult)) * 0.003;
                if (Fc <= 4000) {
                    beta1Result = 0.85;
                } else if (4000 < Fc <= 8000) {
                    beta1Result= ((0.85)-(0.05 * ((Fc - 4000) / (1000))));
                } else {
                    beta1Result= 0.65;
                }
                if (etResult >= 0.005) {
                    tvphiResult= 0.9;
                } else if (0.002 <= etResult < 0.005) {
                    tvphiResult= 0.65 + ((etResult - 0.002) * ((0.25) / (0.005 - 0.002)));
                } else {
                    tvphiResult= 0.00
                }
                tvMnResult= (Fy * As) * (etD - (aResult / 2));
                tvphiMnResult= phiResult * tvMnResult
        }}
}}
```

Comment: _Can anyone see some of my errors?_ Nope, don't see anything. Provide some code please. See [ask]. And welcome on SO

Comment: AxelH: Added the code, was easier to write the question then add the code.

I know there are probably a bunch of errors as this is literally the 1st time I've ever needed to code. I don't expect anyone to do all of this for me of course, any help is appreciated.

Comment: since you said theres alot of errors, theres got to be indicications on which line of codes, can you provide that?

Comment: MVCNoob: There is basically an error on every operation line saying incompatible type. Some say "Required: android.widget.TextView Found: float" others say "Required: android.widget.TextView Found: double", or "Required: java.lang.Float Found: double"

Comment: @EricBellville, take a look at the answer I have posted, this is exactly what I explained about trying to assign the wrong type.

Comment: @AxelH, with the "else if (4000 < Fc <= 8000)" line I'm getting an error with "Operator '<=' cannot be applied to 'Boolean' 'int'". I have a similar error on another line. Besides these two errors, the only one left is on this "tvphiMnResult= phiResult * tvMnResult" line, due to a similar textview float error.

Comment: How didn't see that. You tried to write an interval, but you can't do that, you need to write it in two condition, `4000 < Fc` and `fc <= 8000` Because right now, it read `4000 < Fc`, change it to true/false then read `true/false <= 8000)` explaining your error. So the equivalent is `4000 < Fc && Fc <= 8000`

Comment: @AxelH, thanks!! That fixed those two errors, the only thing left is "tvphiMnResult= phiResult * tvMnResult" one is set as Float the other as TextView. I understand changing float to textview, but how do I change textview to float in this operation to solve the equation correctly?

Comment: Again, using a `*` operator can "only" be done on numeric primitive type. Here you have a TextView (tvMnResult). Just like the assignation, you need to get the value from it ... you've already done that at the beginning of the methods, `getText()` then parsing it. And you are not change a float into a TextView, you are change the Text value of the TextView instance to the Float value

Comment: @AxelH could you help me on this page? I tried some edits, still a few issues. http://stackoverflow.com/q/40923383/7229202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it short, you need to keep the type of each Variable.

Here for example :

```
tvaResult = (Fy * As) / (0.85 * Fc * B);
```

You have

```
TextView = (Float * Float) / ( Double * Float * Float)
TextView = Double // Not possible
```

You are trying to put a Float value into a Instance of `TextView`, this can't be done of course. But you really want to update **the text of the Textview**, so use the methods `setText(String)` of TextView like :

```
tvaResult.setText((Fy * As) / (0.85 * Fc * B) + ""); // Need to be convert into String
```

To change the text to print

This is basicly always the same mistake done, you need to change the text of the TextView an not trying to change the instance itself.

Comment: Thanks! That helped on that one line. I'll try to follow a similar format and logic on the others!

Comment: Just a note, be careful about float calculation, you might be surprise ...