# Redundant error for Android Studio (java) code

Tags: java, android-studio

This is a Calculator program where several inputs are used to create several outputs. The single button on the App that I'm writing runs all the calculations then gives the outputs.

I'm getting one consistent "warning" on the lines under public void onClick

The warning is: `Variable 'aResult' initializer 'Double.parseDouble(tvaResult.getText().toString())'` is redundant

```
    package com.example.ericallenbellville.rcbeamdesign;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnCalc;
    private TextView tvaResult;
    private TextView tvcResult;
    private TextView tvetResult;
    private TextView tvphiResult;
    private TextView tvMnResult;
    private TextView tvphiMnResult;
    private TextView tvbeta1Result;
    private EditText etB,etD,etAs,etFc,etFy;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        btnCalc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        etB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etB);
        etD = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etD);
        etAs = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etAs);
        etFc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFc);
        etFy = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFy);
        tvaResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvaResult);
        tvcResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcResult);
        tvetResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvetResult);
        tvphiResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvphiResult);
        tvMnResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMnResult);
        tvphiMnResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvphiMnResult);
        tvbeta1Result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvbeta1Result);
        btnCalc.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            btnCalc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
            Double B = Double.parseDouble(etB.getText().toString());
            Double  D = Double.parseDouble(etD.getText().toString());
            Double As = Double.parseDouble(etAs.getText().toString());
            Double Fc = Double.parseDouble(etFc.getText().toString());
            Double Fy = Double.parseDouble(etFy.getText().toString());
            Double aResult = Double.parseDouble(tvaResult.getText().toString());
            Double cResult = Double.parseDouble(tvcResult.getText().toString());
            Double etResult = Double.parseDouble(tvetResult.getText().toString());
            Double beta1Result = Double.parseDouble(tvbeta1Result.getText().toString());
            Double phiResult = Double.parseDouble(tvphiResult.getText().toString());
            Double MnResult = Double.parseDouble(tvMnResult.getText().toString());
            Double phiMnResult = Double.parseDouble(tvphiMnResult.getText().toString());
            switch(view.getId() ) {
                case R.id.btnCalc:
                    if (Fc <= 4000) {
                        beta1Result = (0.85);
                    } else if (4000 < Fc && Fc <= 8000) {
                        beta1Result = ((0.85)-(0.05 * ((Fc - 4000) / (1000))));
                    } else {
                        beta1Result = 0.65;
                    }
                    aResult = ((Fy * As) / (0.85 * Fc * B));
                    cResult = (aResult / beta1Result);
                    etResult = (((D - cResult) / (cResult)) * 0.003);
                    if (etResult >= 0.005) {
                        phiResult = (0.9);
                    } else if (0.002 <= etResult && etResult < 0.005) {
                        phiResult = (0.65 + (etResult - 0.002) * 0.25 / (0.005 - 0.002));
                    } else {
                        phiResult = (0.00);
                    }
                    MnResult = (((Fy * As) * (D - (aResult / 2.0))));
                    phiMnResult = phiResult * MnResult;
                    tvaResult.setText(String.valueOf(aResult));
                    tvcResult.setText(String.valueOf(cResult));
                    tvetResult.setText(String.valueOf(etResult));
                    tvphiResult.setText(String.valueOf(phiResult));
                    tvMnResult.setText(String.valueOf(MnResult));
                    tvphiMnResult.setText(String.valueOf(phiMnResult));

            }}
    }
```

Comment: Also, if anyone happens to see anything else that will make this not work, please let me know. I'm just writing this code for a project for class, never coded before other than this.

Comment: `I'm getting one consistent "warning"` ... what is the warning?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I edited the post and added the warning information. sorry. This same warning applies to aResult -> phiMnResult (7 lines).

Comment: It looks like as `aResult` is only used with the `case` statement, then there is not point declaring and initializing it outside of the switch

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tried deleting that line and then it says "cannot resolve symbol 'aResult'" on all the lines that are within the switch. Should I initialize `aResult` within the `case` statement then? Is there another way to initialize `aResult` to make it a usable **symbol** within the `case`?

Comment: I think you have to move that line to with in the `case` block

Comment: @ScaryWombat when I did that is came up with the same warning

Comment: In your question you `Double.parseDouble(tvaResult.getText().toString()())` note the extra `()` but not in your code - which is correct?

Comment: @ScaryWombat fixed that too, sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local variable is redundant java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436155/local-variable-is-redundant-java)